# How can I write these lines of code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to code a form that allows you to add items for a to-do list...
**(jquery code works)**

**These are the lines that I'm stuck:**

> $(document).on('click','.item', myRemove);
>
> $(this).remove();

**This is my HTML code.**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form>
        <label for='textbox'>To Do List</label>
        <input name='textbox' type='text' class='texting' />
    </form>
    <div id="button" onclick="myClick()">Add Item</div>
        <div class="toList">
        </div><!--toList-->

</div><!--wrapper-->
```

**This is what I've done so far with my javascript code.**

```
function myClick(){
    document.getElementById('button').click(myAdd);
    $(document).on('click','.item', myRemove);

}

function myAdd(){
    var texting = document.getElementsByClassName('texting');

    if(texting.length > 0 && texting.value != ''){
        var listItem = texting.value;

        var toList = document.getElementsByClassName('toList');

        toList.appendChild('<div class="item"><span class="del">X</span>' + listItem + '</div>');
    }
}

function myRemove(){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

**This is what I have on my jQuery.**

```
$(document).ready(myClick);


function myClick(){
  $('#button').click(myAdd);
  $(document).on('click','.item',myRemove);
}

  function myAdd(){
    if($('.texting').length > 0 && $('.texting').val() != ''){
        var listItem = $('input[name=textbox]').val();
        $('.toList').append('<div class="item"><span class="del">X</span>' + listItem + '</div>');
    }
  }


function myRemove(){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: My big issue is to write those codes in jQuery into javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the pure JS implementation for what you wanted

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <form>
                <label for='textbox'>To Do List</label>
                <input name='textbox' type='text' class='texting' />
            </form>
            <div id="button" onclick="myClick()">Add Item</div>
            <div class="toList"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function myClick() {
            const list = document.getElementsByClassName('toList')[0];
            const textBox = document.getElementsByClassName('texting')[0];
            const item = document.createElement('div');
            item.setAttribute('class', 'item');
            item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textBox.value));
            
            list.appendChild(item);
        }

        document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.className === 'item') {
                event.srcElement.remove();
            }
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this line:

```
$(document).on('click','.item', myRemove);
```

to this:

```
let items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++)
   items[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => event.srcElement.remove());
```